# How do I get the .which method to work with an and statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I want to make sure that my body fades out only when letters are pressed. With the current code, nothing happens when I press a key between the given range. Even when it is just a normal statement with `event.which === 65`, when I press the key for value 65 which is "A" nothing happens. I've used this property before and made it work but I don't see any syntax difference. Is it because of my selection? Anyway here is the Javascript/jQuery code. Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").hide()
    $("body").fadeIn(3000)
})

$(document).on("keypress", function(event){
    if(event.which ===65){
        $("body").fadeOut(1500)
    }
})
```

Comment: instead of which try `.keyCode`. Its not the syntax but the library i guess. Jquery might have changed the implementation here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So keypress event isn case sensitive therefor code for 'a' is 97 not 65. Try using this code instead:

```
$(document).on("keydown", function(event){
if(event.which ===65){
    $("body").fadeOut(1500)
}
})
```

Also get your semicolons straight

Comment: I think you meant IS case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the following code and it works fine. your error is not in the sample you have shown us.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Here is the body</p>
</body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").hide()
    $("body").fadeIn(3000)
})

$(document).on("keypress", function(event){
    if(event.which ===65){
        $("body").fadeOut(1500)
    }
})
</script>
```